# Can't Access internet through laptop wifi in my xperia u

Tags: connection-issues, reverse-tether

I was able to create a hotspot through Connectify software in my laptop, but when i connect my phone to it ,it shows i am connected but i am not able to access the internet. Is there any option that should be enabled on phone?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a useful post from XDA-Developers website: refer to [this link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1718053).

**Configuring laptop/pc**

1. First, you need to create an adhoc network:
   Open network and sharing center on control panel
   click on manage wireless networks then add , a windows is shown, select create an ad hoc network click on next then input a network name(for example name it 015) then choose the security type (you can select either open or WEP) then check the box save this network
2. Now reopen network and sharing center on control panel then change adapter settings.
   Right click on your internet network and click on properties then select the tab sharing and check the "allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection" (choose wireless network, if multiple networks are shown).
   check also the "allow other network users to control or disable the shared internet connection"
   next click on setting and check all items..
3. Right click on wireless network connection and double click on "internet protocol version 4(tcp/ipv4)"
   on the new window select use the following ip address 192.168.137.1
   and subnet mask 255.255.255.0
   now activate your new adhoc network (if not already) go to the network icon next to the clock and select it and connect.
   Congratulation your laptop/pc is now configured .

---

**Configuring the android device :**

Now, we will configure the android device to make it able to access this new adhoc network

1. Go to setting on the menu of your device
2. then wireless and networks then wi-fi settings then activate wi-fi .
   Right click and choose advanced. Check the "Use static IP"and fill in :

   - ip address: 192.168.137.5 (for example)
   - Gateway : 192.168.137.1
   - Netmask : 255.255.255.0
   - DNS 1: 192.168.137.1
   - DNS 2 : 172.168.137.1
3. right click and save.
   Finally, click on the adhoc network (and input password if you use WEP security) then connect.
4. If you encounter problems connecting ,try to disable then to reactivate wifi, else reboot your android device.

Comment: i tried all ur steps but there is no option like "use static ip" in my phone's advanced wifi setting  . There is abother option in my phone call"Auto IP Support-Assign Auto IP adress if DHCP fails"..any  idea?

Answer (score 0):

after the successfully connected internet to your laptop install and run this software "Virtual Router Plus" and shared connected connection then search for the wifi in any device u can access it by entering correct key.

Comment: ..i tried befor but not warking.Means cant access internet. ty

Answer (score 0):

You need administrator for this.

- Start your hotspot using "Connectify" or "Virtual Router" (which is better IMO as it doesn't shutdown all 30 min like Connectify Free Version)
- Go to network and sharing center on the control panel on your laptop and press on "change adapter settings"
- Right-Click the adapter you are using to connect to the internet and press on the "sharing"-tab.
- Check "Allow other Users in the Network to use this connection as internet connection"
- Select your hotspot network and press okay.
- Restart your hotspot and connect your phone.

You're good to go.