# sharing lan connection to android

Tags: wi-fi, settings, proxy

I have a big problem. In the hostel in which i live has lan facility but theres no wifi in our hostel so i want to share internet through lan connection via wifi hotspot but the problem is this
" lan is provided with proxy settings more over a username and password as authentication" so when i make hotspot it gets connected to phone but no data is transfer between my laptop and mobile. 
HELP ME FRIENDS

Comment: Normally, an ad-hoc network created by laptops will not work directly on Android. You may have a look at answer to the below question:
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/85479/cant-access-internet-through-laptop-wifi-in-my-xperia-u/85500#85500

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Internet Connection Sharing on your lan network.
 To do so you need to:
1.Go to your network icon after connected your LAN cable. Click on " Open network and sharing center."

2.Then click "Local area connection" > "Properties" > "Sharing" Tab and check "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection..." Then click OK > close.